# How do I set the Where clause of an EntityDataSource in the code-behind

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
        PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.ContextTypeName = "Bills.DAL.BillsEntities";
        PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.EnableFlattening = false;
        PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.EntitySetName = "tblPayments_Due";

        PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.Where = "it.UserName = " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.Include = "tblType, tblRepeat";
        PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.EnableUpdate = true;
```

When I delete the Where clause, my gridview returns all records. When I hardcode the same string which is generated from the HttpContexxt string in the HTML, my gridview returns the proper records. However, when I try to use the code above, I get an out of scope message:

'kwingat' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 15.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass it as a parameter

```
PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.Where = "it.UserName = @UserID";
PaymentsDueEntityDataSource.WhereParameters.Add(new Parameter("UserID", TypeCode.Int32,  + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()));
```

Comment: FYI, Where works without parameters.  ...Where("it.OrderID = 1")...works.

Comment: What is this "it." prefix and why is it used?

Comment: @PeterX: that was just cut and pasted from kyle's original post.  The suggestion of using the parameter is the only relevant part of my post.

Comment: I've just stumbled-upon my old comment above - turns-out that the "it." prefix is the default prefix in this Linq (for Entities?) and the only one that works. Not sure why they chose it.

Comment: @kyle could have also fixed the problem by delimiting the value in quotes, but this answer is better: set the condition once, just plug in the part that varies.

Comment: @PeterX: note that the question is using the EntityDataSource, which constructs a LINQ expression. You can set properties, but you don't have complete control over the expression created by the EntityDataSource. There needs to be a convention for the name of an individual object within the EntitySet, so you can add Where and OrderBy properties. "it" is as good a name as any.