# Display dates between two dates in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, date

I have two calendars in my aspx and I want to display records between selected dates of these calendars. My 'TeklifTarih' database attribute is a date type attribute.
Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar><br />
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"></asp:Calendar><br/>
<asp:Button ID="btnClendar" runat="server" Text="İstatistikleri Filtrele" OnClick="btnClendar_Click"/>
```

And my onclick method:

```
protected void btnClendar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baslangicTarihi = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        string bitisTarihi = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString();
        EntityDataSourcePersonel.CommandText =
            "SELECT COUNT(TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan) AS Basari, EmployeeTable.Name, EmployeeTable.Surname, SUM(TeklifTable.TeklifTutar) AS ToplamSatis FROM EmployeeTable JOIN TeklifTable ON TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan = EmployeeTable.EmployeeId WHERE TeklifTable.TeklifTarih >= " + baslangicTarihi + " AND TeklifTable.TeklifTarih <= " + bitisTarihi + " GROUP BY EmployeeTable.Name,EmployeeTable.Surname";
    }
```

I need to display datas with this commandtext and it works when I remove where command of query but I need to filter with these two dates.

Comment: Check the output format of your datetime. If the DB expects different format, the query fails. For example your string is format "dd.MM.yyyy" but the DB date format is "MM/dd/yyyy".

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thanks for answers. Date turns from the program is in format like '01.12.2015 00:00:00' and date format from db is like '2015-12-15'. How can I convert '01.12.2015 00:00:00' to '01-12-2015' ? @Sami

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am using MSSQL @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

You have missed **single quotes** (') while creating a sql statement  your query should be like following:-

```
EntityDataSourcePersonel.CommandText =
"SELECT COUNT(TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan) AS Basari, EmployeeTable.Name, 
 EmployeeTable.Surname, SUM(TeklifTable.TeklifTutar) AS ToplamSatis FROM 
 EmployeeTable JOIN TeklifTable ON TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan = EmployeeTable.EmployeeId 
 WHERE TeklifTable.TeklifTarih >= '" + baslangicTarihi + "' 
 AND TeklifTable.TeklifTarih <= '" + bitisTarihi + "' 
 GROUP BY EmployeeTable.Name,EmployeeTable.Surname";
```

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that i'm not familiar with the `EntityDataSource` control. But according to [what i've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783686/how-do-i-set-the-where-clause-of-an-entitydatasource-in-the-code-behind) you can also use parametrized queries. So do it:

```
String sql = @"SELECT Count(TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan) AS Basari, 
       EmployeeTable.NAME, 
       EmployeeTable.Surname, 
       Sum(TeklifTable.TeklifTutar)        AS ToplamSatis 
FROM   EmployeeTable 
       JOIN TeklifTable 
         ON TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan = EmployeeTable.EmployeeId 
GROUP  BY EmployeeTable.NAME, 
          EmployeeTable.Surname";
EntityDataSourcePersonel.CommandText = sql;
String whereClause = @"TeklifTable.TeklifTarih >= @baslangicTarihi 
                   AND TeklifTable.TeklifTarih <= @bitisTarihi";
EntityDataSourcePersonel.Where = whereClause;
EntityDataSourcePersonel.WhereParameters.Add(new Parameter("baslangicTarihi", TypeCode.DateTime,  Calendar1.SelectedDate));
EntityDataSourcePersonel.WhereParameters.Add(new Parameter("bitisTarihi", TypeCode.DateTime,  Calendar2.SelectedDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Combined with the other answer pointing out you're missing the quotes, and the datetime formatting, the following should work: (not tested though)

```
EntityDataSourcePersonel.CommandText =
"SELECT COUNT(TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan) AS Basari, EmployeeTable.Name, 
EmployeeTable.Surname, SUM(TeklifTable.TeklifTutar) AS ToplamSatis FROM 
EmployeeTable JOIN TeklifTable ON TeklifTable.TeklifHazirlayan = EmployeeTable.EmployeeId 
WHERE TeklifTable.TeklifTarih >= '" + baslangicTarihi.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' 
AND TeklifTable.TeklifTarih <= '" + bitisTarihi.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' 
GROUP BY EmployeeTable.Name,EmployeeTable.Surname";
```

Also consider Tim's point about parameterized queries, you should use them whenever possible.